# Error deploying gwt project with Eclipse/Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven-3, m2eclipse

I started to use Maven in Eclipse (m2eclipse) recently. Unfortunately lately I've been unable to run the application from Eclipse. I get the error:

> Loading modules    src.main.java.com.ohapp.webconfuturo.WebConfuturo
>         Loading inherited module 'src.main.java.com.ohapp.webconfuturo.WebConfuturo'
>            [ERROR] Unable to find 'src/main/java/com/ohapp/webconfuturo/WebConfuturo.gwt.xml' on your
>   classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath
>   entry for source? [ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method

I already checked and the file is there. Isn't visible in Eclipse but is in the file system.

Strangely if I run the program through Maven (mvn gwt:run) it works just fine.

My pom.xml (without the dependencies) is the following:

```
<!-- Dependecies --!>

    <build>


        <!-- Generate compiled stuff in the folder used for development mode -->
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- Need to run the RF Validation tool. This works on both the command-line 
                        and in Eclipse, provided that m2e-apt is installed. -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.web.bindery</groupId>
                        <artifactId>requestfactory-apt</artifactId>
                        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <webResources>
                        <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>

                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}/javascripts</directory>
                            <filtering>false</filtering>
                            <targetPath>js/app</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <unpackVersion>${gae.version}</unpackVersion>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <!--suppress MavenModelInspection -->
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gae-runtime</artifactId>
                        <version>${gae.version}</version>
                        <type>pom</type>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>

                <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see gwt-maven-plugin 
                    documentation at codehaus.org -->
                <configuration>
                    <!-- URL that should be automatically opened in the GWT shell (gwt:run). -->
                    <runTarget>WebConfuturo.html</runTarget>
                    <!-- Ask GWT to create the Story of Your Compile (SOYC) (gwt:compile) -->
                    <compileReport>true</compileReport>
                    <module>com.ohapp.webconfuturo.WebConfuturo</module>
                    <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
                    <style>${gwt.style}</style>

                    <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
                </configuration>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
                        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
                        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <!-- JS is only needed in the package phase, this speeds up testing -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Copy static web files before executing gwt:run -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.1.4,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[0.7.3,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

    </build>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out. The arguments in my Run settings where wrong. I had the the gwt.xml file referenced with full path and not relative to source folder:

```
src.main.java.com.ohapp.appname.AppName
```

I changed it to:

```
com.ohapp.appname.AppName
```

And problem solved.

I don't know how this happened since it wasn't me who made the changes.